# Can we use ModeState.IsValid in view(.cshtml page) in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to show/hide a div on the basis of "ModelState.IsValid" in my view (.cshtml page) in mvc. Is it possible to use ModelState.IsValid in .cshtml? Please send me some link or any idea? Or should I use the other kind of logic like ViewBag?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually check if `ModelState` is `Valid` or not in view.

```
@if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid) {
    ......
    }
```